# Done button on UIPickerView always select last item

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I have implemented a picker view as follows

```
fileprivate var filterPickerView = UIPickerView()
```

With delegate and datasource to the VC

However, I am beginning to face a problem where when the done button is clicked, the picker scrolls to last item and closes. This did not exist initially.

Please I will appreciate any help on this, thank you

the remaining code looks like this:

```
 func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        guard textField == filterPropertyPicker else {
            return
        }
        
        textField.inputView = filterPickerView
    }



 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        guard row < filterComponent.count && row >= 0 else {
            return nil
        }
        
        return filterComponent[row]
    }
    
    // selected filter on segment control actions
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        guard row < filterComponent.count && row >= 0 else {
            return
        }
        viewModel.filterResults(selectedIndex: filterPropertySegments.selectedSegmentIndex, selectedRow: row)
        filterPropertyPicker.text = filterComponent[row]
    }
```

Comment: can you share code?

Comment: can you post your viewModel code?

Comment: Please share done button code as well